# How can I reset Powershell to the default settings?

Tags: powershell

I have changed many powershell policies, such as the Execution policy for running scripts.  Is there a way to get everything back to the default settings when OS was installed?

Answer (score 5):

There is a PowerShell profile file, usually at `C:\Users\UserA\Documents\WindowsPowerShell` that you can edit/remove some customization entries.

When it comes to "resetting services" that is probably something that can be done manually.

e.g. for Execution Policy

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Undefined
```

Additionally, check `C:\Users\UserA\Documents\PowerShell\powershell.config.json` you can actually changed execution policy from there

Answer (score 0):

Here is how:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-7#parameters

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.executionpolicy?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0

> Default. Sets the default execution policy. Restricted for Windows
> clients or RemoteSigned for Windows servers.

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy ; Get-ExecutionPolicy -List | Format-Table -AutoSize
#Cannot set execution policy. Execution policies at the MachinePolicy or UserPolicy scopes must
be set through Group Policy.
Set-Executionpolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Default -Force
Set-Executionpolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Default -Force
Set-Executionpolicy -Scope LocalMachine -ExecutionPolicy Default -Force
Get-ExecutionPolicy ; Get-ExecutionPolicy -List | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Eg:

```
PS C:\Users\Admin> Get-ExecutionPolicy ; Get-ExecutionPolicy -List | Format-Table -AutoSize
Restricted

        Scope ExecutionPolicy
        ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy       Undefined
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process       Undefined
  CurrentUser      Restricted
 LocalMachine      Restricted


PS C:\Users\Admin> Set-Executionpolicy -Scope MachinePolicy -ExecutionPolicy Default -Force
Set-Executionpolicy : Cannot set execution policy. Execution policies at the MachinePolicy or UserPolicy scopes must
be set through Group Policy.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-Executionpolicy -Scope MachinePolicy -ExecutionPolicy Default -Fo ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Set-ExecutionPolicy], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CantSetGroupPolicy,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetExecutionPolicyCommand
PS C:\Users\Admin> Set-Executionpolicy -Scope UserPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Default -Force
Set-Executionpolicy : Cannot set execution policy. Execution policies at the MachinePolicy or UserPolicy scopes must
be set through Group Policy.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-Executionpolicy -Scope UserPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Default -Force
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Set-ExecutionPolicy], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CantSetGroupPolicy,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetExecutionPolicyCommand
PS C:\Users\Admin> Set-Executionpolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Default -Force
PS C:\Users\Admin> Set-Executionpolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Default -Force
PS C:\Users\Admin> Set-Executionpolicy -Scope LocalMachine -ExecutionPolicy Default -Force
PS C:\Users\Admin> Get-ExecutionPolicy ; Get-ExecutionPolicy -List | Format-Table -AutoSize
Restricted

        Scope ExecutionPolicy
        ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy       Undefined
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process      Restricted
  CurrentUser      Restricted
 LocalMachine      Restricted
```